# Very simple Glassfish file transfer

Tags: java, glassfish, client-server, ejb-3.0, file-transfer

I'm trying to combine these articles: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/RMI/rmi_corba/ and http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html to make simple client-server app using Glassfish, in which I could send a file from (local) client to a directory on the (local) server. This is something new for me and I feel a little overwhelmed at the moment. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're kind of in the wrong area. The things you're looking at are for support of RPC sessions. In theory you could send over an enormous byte array, but it is likely unwise to do so.

What would be preferable is to create a simple web app and push the file over HTTP.

Or you could try using a WS Web Service that's configured for [MTOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/) -- it will handle large payloads as well. You can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/mtom.html) for an article of streaming MTOM messages. It's for WebLogic, but it's basically Sun JAX-WS so it should work on Glassfish out of the box.

An advantage of the Web Service is you can host it in an EJB, rather than having to deploy a separate WAR for this facility. What you want to watch out for is having the payload being all stored in RAM. For example, if you want to send a 10Gb file, the actual traffic is going to be the same, but done naively, you will end up holding all 10Gb in the heap on the client and/or the server, which obviously is not desirable.

In the end either way will work. The Web Service had the downside of having to dig in to the shadowy corners of the Web Service stack, where as with a generic Servlet and web app, it's more out in the open, however you will likely be diving in to the inner depths of HTTP to pull that off. For example, if you wanted to use Apache HTTP Client, you would need to create a custom RequestEntity to handle the streaming for you.

All possible, it's just less used and not the default, out of the box, 2 lines of code tutorial example.